# python optimization with custom constraints

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I need to optimize an objective function that is not linear and has more than 10 prams
lets say:

```
def objective([x0....xn])
     ....
    return score
```

and i have a constaint of max min bounds but also of an order of the params x0>x1>x2...>xn
which algorithm in python you think i can  use , i tried scipy minimize but i cant add this kind of constraint( for the order) , i tried also pybads with this constraint and the code failed

```
def constr(x):
            """Return constraints violation"""
            y = np.atleast_2d(x)
            
            a=[np.any([np.any(t[i]<t[i+1]) for i in range(len(t)-1)]) for t in y]
           
            return np.array(a)
from pybads import BADS
        
bads = BADS(
            objective, x0, lower_bounds, upper_bounds,non_box_cons=constr,
            options=options
        )
optimize_result = bads.optimize()
```

Answer (score 0):

> i tried scipy minimize but i cant add this kind of constraint (for the order)

Incorrect. Add a linear constraint where the difference between the next and current decision variable has a minimum (you need to choose this minimum).

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint, Bounds


def objective(x: np.ndarray) -> float:
    c = np.arange(-5, 5)**2
    score = (c*x).dot(c - x)
    return score


increasing_order = LinearConstraint(
    A=np.eye(9, 10, k=1) - np.eye(9, 10),
    lb=np.full(shape=9, fill_value=0.1),
)

result = minimize(
    fun=objective, bounds=Bounds(-0.5, 12), x0=np.zeros(10),
    constraints=increasing_order,
)
assert result.success, result.message
print(result)
```

```
 message: Optimization terminated successfully
 success: True
  status: 0
     fun: -325.83002768919397
       x: [-5.000e-01 -4.000e-01 -3.000e-01 -2.000e-01 -1.000e-01
           -1.319e-10  1.000e-01  2.000e-01  3.000e-01  4.000e-01]
     nit: 6
     jac: [ 6.500e+02  2.688e+02  8.640e+01  1.760e+01  1.200e+00
            0.000e+00  8.000e-01  1.440e+01  7.560e+01  2.432e+02]
    nfev: 22
    njev: 2
```